Unable to Perform API calls When iOS device connected to WiFi IOT device
I have flutter application Which first connect to a WiFi IOT device programatically(This IOT device will emit WiFi but doesn't provide internet) Through wifi... After the connection established I will call a GET Api which is a local IP of that IOT device.... This api will push some data to the IOT device....
But this case now not working in iOS iPhones But this formally worked perfectly without any issues... I can see a iOS permission popup (image) that ask for local Network access eventhough I accept that I got the following error...
Android device the same case working as expected
I'm using iOS 17.5.1. XR Device
https://i.sstatic.net/T8veTsJj.jpg
Whenever I call the get API I got the following error message
ClientException with SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 65), address = 198.158.10.1, port = 2019, uri=http://198.158.10.1:2019/ced_ota_server/ssid_chunk.html?ssid=Beach_bug&pwd=1252253234
This case Working Fine in Debug Mode in Release Mode its Not working
The below code I used to trigger the Local Network Access Popup in Appdelegate when the app is launch
    func triggerLocalNetworkAccessPopup(){
      let networkPer = NetworkPermission()
      networkPer.triggerLocalNetworkPrivacyAlertObjC()
  }

NetworkPermission.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NetworkPermission : NSObject


/*
 This method used to trigger the local network access permission pop up automatically when the app launches (It do it only if it is not already displayed).
 */
-(void) triggerLocalNetworkPrivacyAlertObjC;


@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

NetworkPermission.m file
#import "NetworkPermission.h"

@implementation NetworkPermission

static NSArray<NSData *> * addressesOfDiscardServiceOnBroadcastCapableInterfaces(void) {
    struct ifaddrs * addrList = NULL;
    int err = getifaddrs(&addrList);
    if (err != 0) {
        return @[];
    }
    NSMutableArray<NSData *> * result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (struct ifaddrs * cursor = addrList; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->ifa_next) {
        if ( (cursor->ifa_flags & IFF_BROADCAST) &&
             (cursor->ifa_addr != NULL)
           ) {
            switch (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family) {
            case AF_INET: {
                struct sockaddr_in sin = *(struct sockaddr_in *) cursor->ifa_addr;
                sin.sin_port = htons(9);
                NSData * addr = [NSData dataWithBytes:&sin length:sizeof(sin)];
                [result addObject:addr];
            } break;
            case AF_INET6: {
                struct sockaddr_in6 sin6 = *(struct sockaddr_in6 *) cursor->ifa_addr;
                sin6.sin6_port = htons(9);
                NSData * addr = [NSData dataWithBytes:&sin6 length:sizeof(sin6)];
                [result addObject:addr];
            } break;
            default: {
                // do nothing
            } break;
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(addrList);
    return result;
}

 -(void) triggerLocalNetworkPrivacyAlertObjC {
     
     NSLog(@"triggerLocalNetworkPrivacyAlertObjC called!");
     
    int sock4 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    int sock6 = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    
    if ((sock4 >= 0) && (sock6 >= 0)) {
        char message = '!';
        NSArray<NSData *> * addresses = addressesOfDiscardServiceOnBroadcastCapableInterfaces();
        for (NSData * address in addresses) {
            int sock = ((const struct sockaddr *) address.bytes)->sa_family == AF_INET ? sock4 : sock6;
            (void) sendto(sock, &message, sizeof(message), MSG_DONTWAIT, address.bytes, (socklen_t) address.length);
        }
    }
    
    // If we failed to open a socket, the descriptor will be -1 and it’s safe to
    // close that (it’s guaranteed to fail with `EBADF`).
    close(sock4);
    close(sock6);
}

@end

Any Help on this ?
